# How do I insert a <script> tag on a Django admin page

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to have JavaScript pickup a variable set from the Django admin context. The 'original' object is there already and is the model object I need. But, I need to get the objects name into a variable I can use in my JavaScript.

```
<script>
  var className = "{{ original.__class__.__name__ }}";
</script>
```

I have an Inline and a model Admin that I can use for this, but the Media class will only take files. What I need is a way to insert the above code into an admin template without overriding the template itself. Overriding the template requires me to know where exactly my code will reside which I will not know as this code will be part of a package.

Is there a way to dynamically update the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` settings object? If so then I could use the template method to remedy my problem.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the admin templates?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to override your Admin Templates. Now for this you should create a [Virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and install python and Django in it.

After that you can find out your django path by opening a python console with: `python`

Type the follwing into the console:

```
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import django
print(django.__path__)
```

This will output the path of your django install. If you're using a virtualenv it's usually something like:

> ~/myproject/env/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/django

So the admin templates are in :

> ~/myproject/env/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin

There you can add a script tag just as in normal django templates.

Note that the virtualenv is just a recommendation. You don't have to use it but it's usually better to do so since it doesn't affect all python/django project but only the one you are using the env for.

Comment: I'm already using a virtual environment, but your solution will not work in my case, because I'm building a package not a site. This will eventually be a plugin to Django and I'll have no idea where the end user will have it installed.